# I executed this code, But it showed type error like this "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, frontend

I executed this code, But it showed a type error like this "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"

I implement a crud application to manage student data. This is the data retrieving code. I used the database as mongo DB databases. But when is being executed the code this type of error showed.

"**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map**')"

```
export default function Home() {
  const [student, setStudent] = useState("");
  const [totage, setTotal] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/student").then((res) => {
      if (res.data.success) {
        setStudent(res.data.existingData);
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: Did you read the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in the code you are missing an array in the use state. Please change it in the below format.

```
 const [student, setStudent] = useState([]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this code to get the answers

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default class CreateResponse extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      groupid:"",
      name: "",      
    };
  }

  handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { groupid ,name } = this.state;

    const data = {
      groupid:groupid,
      name: name,      
    };

    console.log(data);

    axios.post("https://locallhost/5000/save", data).then((res) => {
      if (res.data.success) {        
          this.setState({
            groupid:"",
            name: "",           
          });
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (     
                <h2>Provide Response for students</h2>


<div>
      <h1>Add student Details</h1>
      <form>
        <label>Name </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="name"
          placeholder="input name"
          value={this.state.groupid}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
        <br /> <br />
        <label>Age </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="age"
          placeholder="input age"
          value={this.state.groupid}
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
        <br/><br/>

<button onClick={onSubmit} type='submit'>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>

)}





import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default class ViewCart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      Carts: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.retrieveCarts();
  }

  retrieveCarts() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/mycart").then((res) => {
      if (res.data.success) {       
        this.setState({
          Carts: res.data.existingCarts,
        });

        console.log(this.state.Carts);
        
      }
    });
  }
  

  
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ marginLeft: "100px" }}>
        <br />
        <br />
        <h1>View My Cart</h1>
        <br />       
        <br />       
        
        <table border="1" style={{ width: "80%" }}>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th style={{ padding: "10px" }}>No </th>
              <th>Item ID </th>
              <th>Item Name </th>           
              <th>Discount (%) </th>
              <th>Price (Rs) </th>                   
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.state.Carts.map((Carts, index) => (
              <tr key={index}>
                <th scope="row" style={{ padding: "10px" }}>
                  {index + 1}
                </th>
                <td>{Carts.itemid}</td>
                <td>{Carts.itemname}</td>                        
                <td>{Carts.discount}</td>
                <td>{Carts.price}</td>                
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <br />
        <br />
        
        <button type="submit" >
          <a href={`/viewitems`} style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "black" }}>
            &nbsp; Back &nbsp;
          </a>       
        </button>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button type="submit">
          <a
            href={`/addpurchase`}
            style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "black" }}
          >
            Purchase Bill
          </a>
        </button>
        <br />       
        <br />                
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```